# How to get value from date picker in katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio

I want to get value from date picker (get date from date picker and stored in to variable) in katalon.

Comment: Please share some HTML. Around the date picker you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Java programming language and get your datepicker Date from Java code. Do not forget to include the import statement at the top of the test case for the java.util... library you get the datepicker from.